# Show that the matrix is a symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $T:V\to V$ be a symmetric linear map i.e $\langle Tx,y\rangle =\langle x,Ty\rangle,\;$ $V$ is a finite dimensional inner product space.

If $\{e_i:1\leq i\leq n\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $V$ then show that the matrix $A$ of $T$ w.r.t. this basis is a symmetric matrix.

**My try**:

To show a matrix is symmetric, I will have to find the matrix of  $T$ under the given orthonormal basis which can't be done here. So how to check whether the matrix $A$ is symmetric on that. Please throw some light here?

Answer (score 4):

Sure, let's write $Te_i = \displaystyle \sum a_{ij}e_j$. Observe that $$a_{ij} = \langle \sum a_{ik}e_k, e_j \rangle = \langle Te_i, e_j \rangle = \langle e_i, Te_j \rangle = \langle e_i, \sum a_{jl}e_l \rangle  = a_{ji}.$$ Hence the matrix of $T$ in the orthonormal basis is symmetric.

Comment: thank you very much its great!!